# How to remove modal.js from all pages in magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, modal-popup

because of this file modal.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'mage/template',
    'text!ui/template/modal/modal-popup.html',
    'text!ui/template/modal/modal-slide.html',
    'text!ui/template/modal/modal-custom.html',
    'Magento_Ui/js/lib/key-codes',
    'jquery/ui',
    'mage/translate'
], function ($, _, template, popupTpl, slideTpl, customTpl, keyCodes) {
    'use strict';
..
```

in website all pages these modal-popup content is being called but when you see its source code there is no modal.js exist.
please help me remove this.

Comment: Did you ever find solution for this? If you have, please add it in answer, that would really helpful