# How to remove modal.js and its related files

Tags: magento2, script, modal-popup, modal

I need to remove modal.js and it's related files all over the website. It is available in vendor directory and I need to remove it from DOM.

I found similar question, but no one answered it:
[How to remove modal.js from all pages in magento 2.2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/220194/how-to-remove-modal-js-from-all-pages-in-magento-2-2)

I have also tried remove tag and add modal related js file names in it but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI Modal is a global UI component and it is using **on-demand** (it means you cannot remove it with XML structs like `<remove src="modal.js"/>` or something similar).

It's not only using on the frontend, but it is also using widely in adminhtml as well. For e.g:

> src/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/category/tree.phtml

[image: src/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/category/tree.phtml]

It is a part of Magento Minicart (Cart Sidebar)

> src/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/sidebar.html

[image: src/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/sidebar.html]

However, if you don't want to use the authentication popup functionality (login popup in Checkout page). You can try to remove that block in XML by using this

```xml
<referenceBlock name="authentication-popup" remove="true"/>
```

Completely removing `Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal` is impossible in Magento 2! It will break a lot of functionalities for sure. Of course, in theory, you still can disable the whole functionality of `modal` UI with a JS mixin like this:

```js
/**
 * StackOverflow No Modal :(
 *
 * @category  Mage
 *
 * @author    Toan Nguyen <https://github.com/nntoan>
 */
define([
    'jquery',
    'uiRegistry',
    'mage/utils/wrapper',
    'mage/validation'
], function ($, registry, wrapper) {
    'use strict';

    return function (modal) {

        modal.prototype._create = wrapper.wrap(modal.prototype._create, function (original) {
            return null;
        });

        return modal;
    };
});
```

If I was misunderstanding you, feel free to leave a comment :)

Comment: Wow! Your answer is very helpful for me to understand modal js in Magento.

Comment: @ShoaibMunir You're welcome, I suggest you take a look into the Magento DevDocs, it's really really helpful and it's improving by the time. For e.g: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/search.html?q=Overview+of+UI+components

Answer (score 1):

> To remove the static resources, linked in a page , make a change similar to the following in a theme extending
>    **`app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`**:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <head>
        <!-- Remove local resources -->
        <remove src="css/styles-m.css" />
        <remove src="my-js.js"/>
        <remove src="Magento_Catalog::js/compare.js" />

    <!-- Remove external resources -->
        <remove src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
        <remove src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>
        <remove src="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" /> 
   </head>
</page>
```

Reference: [Remove static resources](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_css_remove)

Comment: I really appreciate you took time to answer my question. Thanks!